# How to access javascript library delivered through a remote resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, cdn

I'm trying to develop an API javascript package that developers can use to access and interact in my application. I want the developers to access the APIs by using a CDN script at the head of their own application and call the needed resources where appropriate. I similar example to what I'm attempting is google's recapthca. The idea is as follows:

1. Load the package from the CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.example.com/package.js"></script>
```

2. Use the library from the package as needed

```
package.init('demo-button', {
     resoruceId: '506e2f7c-eaef-4136-9ba2-8ccb116a0480',
});
```

However, I'm struggling to make the `package` available in the client host, and I kept getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: package is not defined`.

This is my **src/index.js** file:

```
const package = (function () {
    const init = function (buttonId, config) {
        console.log('Initializing Orionis with config:', config);
    };

    const publicAPI = {
        init: init
    };

    return publicAPI;
})();

export default orionis
```

This is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "package-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "CDN SDK",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./src/components/main.css --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

This is my **server.js** file:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
const port = 4000

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });

app.use(express.static('dist'))

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

This is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'package',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Any guidance or advice on how to solve this will be helpful